# Android app icon move inside left corner

Tags: android, icons

When my activity opened, I need to move application icon which is displayed on left side of action bar to bit left inside

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom view for the Action Bar - see [example](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android)

Comment: If you want to do it without having a custom view in Action Bar, you can try to remove and hide the `Up` button on top left. I think that this will move your icon to more left since it will also occupy the space of it. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're wanting to do is have your icon not butt up so close to the left edge of the screen just provide a custom drawable that has a little extra transparent padding on the left side.  I've done it.  Works like a charm.